# Using webcam over rdp

Tags: webcam, rdp

Good day, I will like to know if theres a way to use my webcam over rdp (windows server 2019). Please assist me anyone. I have a laptop a with an amazing webcam and also a microsoft external webcam. Thanks and am open to any suggestions to make it work.